# Consuming ASP.NET(Asmx) web service (Cocoa/Objective-C)

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have ASP.NET webservice(Asmx) which I need to consume in Cocoa/Objective-C. What is the simplest/optimal way to achieve this? I have done the implementation where we have many delegates for XMLParser and connection. like didStartElement, didEndElement....

Is there any other way to achieve this? In .NET I have done a similar implementation where I have a proxy class and when I make a call to the web method I get a response which is the return value of the web method rather than parsing the response xml.

Please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Try out some of the existing network frameworks before writing your own (RESTKit, AFNetworking, etc.) - They all have good tutorials on how to easily consume webservices.

A little bit off-topic, but it seems that your Webservice returns a XML response. I would (but that's just me!) try to change that to JSON. Cocoa/Obj-C provides built-in functions to deserialize JSONs, and the aforementioned frameworks also work quite well with this format. It's far easier to use than NSXMLParser etc.